# Copying values of array at specific indices to another array

Tags: java, arrays

I came up to a situation where I have an array and I need to copy some specific attributes (i.e. values at specific indinces) not the whole array to another array.

For example if the initial array is:

```
double[] initArray = {1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 5.0, 4.5};
```

then if I wanted to copy only 2nd, 4th and 5th attribute (i.e. values at these indices) the desired output array would be:

```
double[] reducedArray = {2.0, 5.0, 4.5};
```

I know that if the indices appear in a sequential form, e.g. 1-3 then I can use [`System.arraycopy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2371568/3584765) but my indices does not have that aspect.

So, is there any official way to do this, besides the trivial loop through each value and copy the ones needed:

```
double[] includedAttributes = {1, 4, 5};
double[] reducedArray = new double[includedAttributes.length];
for(int j = 0; j < includedAttributes.length; j++) {
    reducedArray[j] = initArray[includedAttributes[j]];
}
```

Comment: Is there any restrictions to using ArrayLists, for example? This way you could have an `ArrayList<Double> temp`, and then just add all the desired numbers there. After everything, you can get the `double[]` array by invoking `temp.toArray(new double[]{})`. You can do this with pure arrays too, of course. This is just a dirty, simple and easy method

Comment: Java 8 Streams might be what you are looking for. Or is that Pre-8 ?

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja although there is not any specific restriction, I would go for `ArrayList` due to autoboxing.

Comment: @Fildor I am using Java 7 but anyway it could interesting to know this.

Comment: Then maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552005/is-there-a-concise-way-to-iterate-over-a-stream-with-indices-in-java-8

Answer (score 2):

Using streams, it's a one-liner.

Given:

```
int[] indices;
double[] source;
```

Then:

```
double[] result = Arrays.stream(indices).mapToDouble(i -> source[i]).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply said, its not possible, unless you have a specific case.

for example:

You want the top N items with highest value (in your case {2.0,4.5,5.0})

A quick(and dirty) way of doing it:

```
public static double[] topvalues(int n,double[] original){
 double[] output=new double[n];
 Arrays.sort(original);
 System.arraycopy(original,0,output,0,n);
 return output;
}
```

**NOTE**: this method also sorts your original array as well. if you don't want this behaviour there are different methods to use, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is a list of them :

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question in a way perhaps not sought-after, you could write a class for this kind of operation:

```
public class PointerArray <T> {

    private T[] arr;
    private int[] indices;

    public PointerArray(T[] arr, int[] indices) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.indices = indices;
    }

    public T get(int index) {
        return this.arr[this.indices[index]];
    }

    public void set(int index, T value) {
        this.arr[this.indices[index]] = value;
    }

    public int size() {
        return this.indices.length;
    }

}
```

This is untested code, but the idea in the very least should get through.

Using it would look something like this:

```
int[] includedAttributes = {0, 3, 4};

PointerArray<Double> reducedArray =
    new PointerArray<Double>(initArray, includedAttributes);

for(int j = 0; j < reducedArray.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(reducedArray.get(j));
}
```

This is performance- and memory-wise, I think, a good solution, since nothing is copied (nor created). Only drawback is the need to call `get()`, but I have no idea how expensive method calls really are.